# Does Appium v1.6.4 support Android v6.0.1?

Tags: android, ubuntu, automation, appium

When I run my testautomation on Android v6.0.1 it always comes up with KeyError: 'touchAction' error.
Using Selenium v3.0.1 (no luck on v3.4.1 as well)
On the other Appium version code worked smoothly.
Does Appium v1.6.4 support Android v6.0.1?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Update in following file : C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib \adb.js

In Line no 1041 Update ((outline.indexOf(name) !== -1) to if ((outline.indexOf(name) !== -1) && !(outline.indexOf("bad pid") > -1))